# change the writing language to arabic when text field is clicked

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

The default writing language on my PC is English. What should I add to my code, so when I press on the text field in j frame, I want the writing language to convert automatically into Arabic. And when I press on another text field, I want it to return into English.

Answer (score 0):

How the writting language affect your application? For example, in firefox I can change the writting language by right click on any box and change the language.

If your app needs to keep track the current language you need to save the language configuration somewhere (on a global variable or file), and perhaps make a good first guess reading it from the `LANG` environment variable.